# Opencv and Photoshop CS5.1 brightness contrast

Tags: c++, opencv, photoshop, brightness, contrast

I don't know is this would be a right question, but in my application i need to operate with image contrast/brightness and the photoshop functions works pretty well, i installed opencv and tried [this realization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.htm)

for contrast an brightness but it's not the same result as photoshop functions so that's not what i want, so my question is which algorithm photoshop cs 5.1 uses for changing brightness contrast (image->adjustments->brightness (-150,150) /contrast (-50,50). Maybe someone could help me?

Comment: Visit this link for the full explanation on the photoshop brightness and contrast adjustment. http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/brightness-contrast/